# Returned from call to mpiexec

Tags: mpi

When you call mpiexec, what is returned if it has executed successfully? I want to use whatever is returned by mpiexec to gauge how many successful runs of a code that I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpiexec` returns the error code of the first process that fails or zero if all processes are executed successfully. Source: http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man1/mpiexec.1.php

You should write your output to a file (for instance using the stdout).

Comment: This is true for Open MPI, but not necessarily for all MPI implementations. The MPI Standard does not define this behavior. The real answer is that there isn't a way to find this out directly from the return code.

Comment: That's true. However it is quite natural to return the error code (since one can see `mpiexec`) as a process itself (who "happens" to start up new processes). Furthermore I assume most implementations will follow some standard (why should `openMPI` use another exit code). But you're totally right one should be careful.

Comment: The MPI standard recommends that quality UNIX or POSIX implementations should pass the error code passed to `MPI_Abort()` as the return value of `mpiexec`. Open MPI does not follow this recommendation.

Comment: In what sense does `mpiexec` does not follow the recommendation? If one uses `MPI_Abort()`, it's clear something went wrong.